# Modifying session attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, session, attributes

Is it possible to change session attribute using jquery? If yes, please explain how to do that as I can't find any information?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. You would need to make an AJAX request to a server-side script which would then amend the session variable as needed.